# Como busco por query name estoy trabajando con la api de rawg

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, express, routes

Me encuentro trabajando en la api de rawg, y quisiera traer videojuegos por name, mediante query. pero al momento de hacer la busque por thunderclient me devuelve toda la api, y no la busqueda en concreto. adjunto mi codigo de dicha funcion.

CONTROLLER:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HANDLER:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

LA API: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MI RESULTADO DE BUSQUEDA (ME TRAE TODOS LOS RESULTADOS) NO PRECISAMENTE EL QUE BUSCO:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y LA DEFINICION DE MIS RUTAS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código como texto.

Comment: Bienvenido, edita tu pregunta, agregando el código como texto para que sea visible a toda la comunidad, te invitamos a revisar [ask], saludos.